# Textfield not showing any text in MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip, clock, digital

im building this interface in FLASH CS5, where i want to place a digital clock, i created a MovieClip InstanceName "RELOJ" in that MovieClip i have two layers, one with two Text Fields that are going to display Time and the other the Date, and on the other layer is the actionscript (AS3) of the whole clock and date.

ok, now i place that movieclip on my Main TimeLine, i play the swf but i dont see the clock working.

I have tried placing an Actions layer on my main timeline and writing "RELOJ.play()" but nothing...

How do i play that MovieClip?

**UPDATE:** This is the code inside the MovieClip. The Fonts are Embedded.

```
dateDisplay.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showTime);
diaDisplay.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showDia);

function showTime(event:Event):void {

  var myTime:Date = new Date();

  var theSeconds=myTime.getSeconds();
  var theMinutes=myTime.getMinutes();
  var theHours=myTime.getHours();
  var ampm:String;


  if (theHours>=12) {
    ampm="pm";
  } else {
    ampm="am";
  }

  if (theHours>=13) {
    theHours=theHours-12;
  }

  if (String(theMinutes).length == 1) {    
    theMinutes="0"+theMinutes; 
  } 
  if (String(theSeconds).length == 1) {     
    theSeconds="0"+theSeconds; 
  } 

  dateDisplay.text =theHours+":"+theMinutes+":"+theSeconds+" "+ampm;
} 

function showDia(event:Event):void {

var myDia:Date = new Date();

var dayText:String;

var theDia=myDia.getDay();
var theFechaDia=myDia.getDate();

if(theDia == 0) {
    dayText = "Domingo";
    } else if(theDia == 1) {
      dayText = "Lunes";
        } else if(theDia == 2) {
        dayText = "Martes";
            } else if(theDia == 3) {
            dayText = "Miercoles";
                } else if(theDia == 4) {
                dayText = "Jueves";
                    } else if(theDia == 5) {
                    dayText = "Viernes";
                        } else if(theDia == 6) {
                        dayText = "Sabado";
}


diaDisplay.text =dayText+" "+theFechaDia;

 }
```

Comment: Do you see anything? My guess is that you have not embedded any fonts. Please post some code if you want more help.

Comment: @Mattias I have updated the post with the code inside my movieclip.

Comment: @mattias I have updated the post with the code inside my movieclip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your textfield. Make it dynamic. Select what characters you want to embed. Test again. If nothing changes, add som graphics to the movieclip so you know it shows.

[image]

---

Your code works fine ...

[image]

Comment: it has a background graphic that i can see when i run the swf, and the textfield is dynamic. But i still cant see the time or date.

Comment: What font are you using? And are you embedding it correctly using the Character Embedding?

Comment: Im using the Segoe UI font, its the one on the Metro UI interface of Windows 8. And yes i embedded it correctly, it shows the font on my library.

Comment: i've tried that.. i dondt understand why it doesnt show... I have also copied it to a new fla and pasted it on the main timeline of that new fla, but nothing. Its weird.

Comment: hey! i got it to work, i changed the font but this time i saved the file, then chaged the font back played the swf and now i can see the time and the date. Oh man this was bugging me since yesteardy. THANK YOU SO MUCH for the time you took to help me.